# Json Type Provider: Parsing Valid Json Fails

Tags: json, f#, type-providers, f#-data

I have the following code block in my REPL

```
#r "../packages/FSharp.Data.2.2.1/lib/net40/FSharp.Data.dll"

open FSharp.Data

[<Literal>]
let uri = "http://www.google.com/finance/option_chain?q=AAPL&output=json"

type OptionChain = JsonProvider<uri>
```

When I run it, FSI is returning

> Error 1   The type provider `'ProviderImplementation.JsonProvider'`
>   reported an error: Cannot read sample JSON from
>   `'http://www.google.com/finance/option_chain?q=AAPL&output=json'`:
>   Invalid JSON starting at character 1, snippet =
>   ---- `{expiry:{y:2`
>   ----- `json =`
>   ------ `{expiry:{y:2015,m:5,d:8},expirations:  [{y:2015,m:5,d:8},{y:2015,m:5,d:15},`

This json is valid according to two other sites.  Is it a bug in the TP?

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/ is a good tool to validate potential JSON text. As pointed out by Ming-Tang the document isn't valid JSON as the keys are quoted. http://json.org/ tells us that keys must be strings  which must be quoted. Now it's possible the TP should be more lax as this is a common misunderstanding but then where would you draw the line as there are many more misunderstandings. I believe it's better to be strict in the long run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output isn't valid JSON because some keys are not quoted.

```
{expiry:{y:2015,m:5,d:8},expirations:[{y:2015,m:5,d:8},{y:2015,m:5,d:15},{y:2015,m:5,d:22},{y:2015,m:5,d:29},{y:2015,m:6,d:5},{y:2015,m:6,d:12},{y:2015,m:6,d:19},{y:2015,m:6,d:26},{y:2015,m:7,d:17},{y:2015,m:8,d:21},{y:2015,m:10,d:16},{y:2016,m:1,d:15},{y:2017,m:1,d:20}],
 puts:[{cid:"43623726334021",s:"AAPL150508P00085000",e:"OPRA",p:"-",c:"-",b:"-",a:"-",oi:"-",vol:"-",strike:"85.00",expiry:"May 8, 2015"},
 ...
```